# JS element style switching

Tags: javascript, html

I need to switch my element background image beetwin two images on every click on it.

I have this, byt it swithes color just two times =\

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascript Change Div Background Image</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    #div1 {
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    background-image:url(blue.png);
    }


    </style>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function changeDivImage() {
            var imgPath = new String();
            imgPath = document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage;

            if (imgPath == "url(blue.png)" || imgPath == "") {
                document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = "url(green.png)";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = "url(blue.png)";
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <center>
    <p>
        This Javascript Example will change the background image of<br />
        HTML Div Tag onclick event.
    </p>
    <div id="div1">
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Change Background Image" onclick="changeDivImage()" />
    </center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try alerting the `imgPath` to see if the `url(green.png)` gets resolved to the full url path of the image, in which case the if will fail.. also check to see (more likely) if the browser adds quotes around the url..

Comment: Why don't you use CSS classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some browsers are likely giving you the absolute path to the image instead of the relative path you are providing.

Instead of `==`, test for the `indexOf()` position of the url.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/7Rp2G/2/ *(click the button several times to see the url change)*

```
function changeDivImage() {
    var imgPath = new String();
    var div = document.getElementById("div1");
    imgPath = div.style.backgroundImage;

    div.style.backgroundImage = (imgPath.indexOf("blue.png") > -1 || imgPath == "") 
                              ? "url(green.png)" 
                              : "url(blue.png)";

}​
```

**EDIT:** Updated to replace the `if()` with a ternary.

Answer (score 1):

The following code should take care of it.

```
var current_bg = 'green';

function changeDivImage()
{

    if(current_bg == 'green')
    {

        current_bg = 'blue';

    }
    else
    {

        current_bg = 'green';

    }

    document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = "url('"+current_bg+".png')";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to quote the url, that is

```
backgroundImage = "url('blue.png')"
```

I would guess the browser is doing that for you now, which makes the comparison fail. A guess.. A more stable solution might be to maintain a variable to keep track of the current background image instead of comparing strings in css properties.

Comment: No, quotes are not neccessary.